# How can I achieve a Kuwahara painted effect in Blender?

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine, texture-painting, texture-baking

An example of this effect in action, and code for Unity [can be seen here](http://shaderslab.com/demo-63---oil-painting.html).

I'm somewhat new to shader coding and converting such work to Blender - I don't suppose anybody has any suggestions on how to accomplish the effect, or even where best to get started?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a shader, reminded me I Bookmarked this https://github.com/MeteHanC/Python-Median-Filter  to make really noisy cycles renders oil painting-ish.

Comment: @batFINGER - Heyy, that's pretty interesting. I wonder how I could incorporate that with Blender. I'm a decent Unity C# programmer, but this is going a little beyond my knowledge. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

This has been added:

Summary:

The filter is used to reduce noise while preserving edges. It can be used to create a cartoon effect from photorealistic images.

The idea is to offer two modes:

Classic aka isotropic kuwahara filter: simple and faster computation. Algorithm splits an area around a single pixel in four parts and computes the mean of the region with the lowest standard deviation

Anisotropic Kuwahara filter: improve the classical approach by considering the direction of structures of regions

https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/107015

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: This filter is still experimental and you have to enable it, but in Blender 3.6 there is no “Full Frame Compositor" as described here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/compositor-new-node-kuwahara-filter/29205