# Can you use Python to create custom compositor nodes?

Tags: python, scripting, compositing-nodes, npr

I want to create a [Kuwahara Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuwahara_filter) within Blender according to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDhN-JK3U9g. Is it possible to write a custom node for this kind of filter within Blender?

If it is possible, what are some resources I can look into to learn about scripting compositing nodes?

Comment: You could write a CPU shader in OSL, otherwise you can design a custom group using existing nodes.

Comment: I've added a less irritating link in your question, with greater density of information. In general, posts should not depend on external links but here, the _central_ question is not dependent. You may be interested in [this project](https://github.com/bitsawer/blender-custom-nodes), although it's rather old, now.

Comment: @RobinBetts May I ask why did you find the link irritating? I'm thinking of making some educational Youtube videos myself, but haven't yet figured a theme.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Welllll... I'm no expert.. but perhaps, here are a few pointers. 1. The 'Shocked Face' thumbnail. Curiously, omitted by  the link in question. 2. Give the video a title about one thing, and then spend most of it talking about something else. Chiefly, of course, yourself. 'How you personally feel about..' is a great cue-card, here. (Your dog... pineapple on pizza.. etc.). 3. Sound is important. Start  with: 'What's up, guys?' and ensure there's an irrelevant background track, levelled up enough to obscure narration and make concentration impossible. Hmm.. running out of roo

Comment: @RobinBetts Hahah, I've never seen you that irritated! That's a great recipe I will try to avoid.

Comment: Kuwahara Filter has been added to Blender: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/177355/60486